# Inquiry Regarding Retrieving Custom Product Orders and Location of Custom Information in OrderItem Response - SP-API

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-selling-partner-api, amazon-fba

I am trying to retrieve Amazon orders that involve custom products using the OrderItems API within SP-API. Specifically, I am interested in understanding where the custom information is stored within the OrderItem response. Is it located in the "BuyerCustomizedInfoDetail" or another section? Your clarification will greatly assist me in properly handling custom product data.

Thank you for your assistance.